# How do I disable the emacs flyspell middle mouse correction?

Tags: flyspell, yank

I already use middle mouse to paste/yank. However flyspell seems to hijack this, making it impossible to paste in the vicinity of a correctable word.

With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973000/emacs-23-4-mouse-2-behaviour-on-os-x-10-7) I have discovered that I can add the correct-word functionality to the more sane right-mouse button with

```el
(eval-after-load "flyspell"
  '(progn
     (define-key flyspell-mouse-map [down-mouse-3] #'flyspell-correct-word)
     (define-key flyspell-mouse-map [mouse-3] #'undefined)))
```

however this doesn't change the middle mouse button behaviour.

How do I clear flyspell's default binding of the middle mouse so I can always use middle mouse to paste? It would also be appreciated if the relevant lisp could be explained. Although I managed to copy and paste the above to good effect, it's inner workings are a mystery to me.

Comment: Just a guess, by maybe bind `[mouse-2]` and `[down-mouse-2]` to `nil` in `flyspell-mouse-map`?

Comment: @Dan That's the answer. `mouse-2` is middle mouse button. To confirm, hit `C-h c <middle mouse button click>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend your current code to bind `[mouse-2]` and `[down-mouse-2]` to `nil` in `flyspell-mouse-map`:

```el
(eval-after-load "flyspell"
  '(progn
     (define-key flyspell-mouse-map [down-mouse-3] #'flyspell-correct-word)
     (define-key flyspell-mouse-map [mouse-3] #'undefined)
     (define-key flyspell-mouse-map [down-mouse-2] nil)
     (define-key flyspell-mouse-map [mouse-2] nil)))
```

Thanks to @nanny for testing it out.

What the code is doing is:

- Telling emacs that you want to make some modifications only *after* it loads `flyspell` (that's the `eval-after-load` part).
- The `progn` tells emacs that you're going to tell it to do a number of things.
- Each of the `define-key` lines tells emacs that you're going to change something in the `flyspell-mouse-map`.
- Setting a binding to `nil` tells emacs that it should do nothing in that map.

In other words: unbinding it in `flyspell-mouse-map` means that `flyspell` won't override your existing middle-mouse-as-yank setup.